# ASP.NET WEb API won't Authorize even if I'm logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

It keeps on forwarding me to login page despite the fact that I'm logged in while testing from Postman REST Client. How can I authorize?

```
[Authorize]
public class AttendancesController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AttendancesController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Attend([FromBody]int gigId)
    {
        var attendance = new Attendance()
        {
            GigId = gigId,
            AttendeeId = User.Identity.GetUserId()
        };
        _context.Attendances.Add(attendance);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your login method?

Comment: Are you using the browser version of Postman or the stand alone version of Postman? The stand alone requires an additional piece called Interceptor to use the browser cookies for things like authentication

Comment: I am using a browser version Doc.

Comment: Are you passing accesstoken in request header as `Authorization` key ?

Comment: No amit, how can I do that?